# Why can I pass two parameter to Event class

Tags: f#

When I look the definition of event class in f#

```
type Event<'T> =
 class
  new Event : unit -> Event<'T>
  member this.Trigger : 'T -> unit
  member this.Publish :  IEvent<'T>
 end
```

I can pass only one type on event class like

```
let nameChanged = new Event<unit>()
```

But I saw some sample too, that pass two variables like

```
let propertyChanged = Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
```

How could be that be possible?

And when I implement an interface like

```
module SapHandler

open SAP.Middleware.Connector

type Connector() =

    let configurationChanged = Event<RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler, RfcConfigurationEventArgs>()  

    interface IDestinationConfiguration with
        member self.ChangeEventsSupported() =
            false
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member self.ConfigurationChanged = configurationChanged.Publish
```

The compiler complain:

```
The type 'RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler' has a non-standard delegate type
```

Why?
The definition of delegate type is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible because there's another [class too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370292.aspx):

```
type Event<'Delegate,'Args (requires delegate)> =
 class
  new Event : unit -> Event<'Delegate,'Args>
  member this.Trigger : obj * 'Args -> unit
  member this.Publish :  IEvent<'Delegate,'Args>
 end
```

You're getting that error because your delegate for the event is probably missing the first `object` `sender` argument which is standard in .net. You can use [`Control.DelegateEvent<'Delegate>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370450.aspx) to get around this

```
let propertyChanged = DelegateEvent<RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler>()
```

Comment: How do you know that Event class need object sender as first argument? When I am looking at class signature, I can't see object sender anywhere.

Comment: @zero_coding it's this: `member this.Trigger : obj * 'Args -> unit` the obj is the sender argument, the docs also mention it: "Event implementations for a delegate types following the standard .NET Framework convention of a first sender argument."